# Simple PHP Array Problem - IF EXIT

Tags: php, arrays

how can i convert this into an array?
if someone searches for "lo" he gets the text "no query", but how can i do this for more words? i tried it with array('1','2')..

```
if ($query == 'lo')
{
  exit ('No Query.');
}
```

i want something like this

```
if ($query == 'lo', 'mip', 'get')
{
  exit ('No Query.');
}
```

so, if someone types mip he gets the message..
thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if ($query == 'lo' || $query == 'mip' || $query == 'get') {
    exit('No query');
}
```

Or if you might want to add many strings to check for, try using an array.

```
$bad_words = array('lo', 'mip', 'get', ... );
if (in_array($query, $bad_words)) {
    exit('No query');
}
```

Then adding new 'bad words' is as easy as adding them to the array.

Comment: Maybe using 

    in_array(strtolower($query), $bad_words)

would be better?

Cheers

Comment: @lunohodov yep, assuming no prior manipulation/validation has been done, that would be better

Answer (score 0):

Your array should look like this:

```
$array = array('lo', 'mip', 'get');
```

Now Search

```
if (in_array('mip', $array))
{
  echo 'We have a match';
}
else
{
  echo 'No match';
}
```